# jms 1.2 / jndi version information

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jndi

I am working on an application that is using jms 1.2 version, pulling the dependency from maven repos, using groupId - javax.jms, and artifactId as jms, version as 1.2.

But surprisingly, I can't find any information on JMS 1.2 version from J2EE release information etc. they are just showing a jump from jms 1.1 to 2.0. For e.g. this wiki page

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history

My main question is, what version of jndi does this version use? Ours is a stand alone Java application that uses

- Java 8
- Tibco EMS with tibjms 6.3 and jms 1.2

How to find out what version of jndi does this setup mean? Thanks.

Comment: JNDI has been bundled with the JRE for many years and several major releases, and hasn't had a new version since 2007 IIRC. The version of JMS doesn't have anything to do with the version of JNDI. Unclear what you're asking,

Comment: @EJP all I am trying to find is what version of jndi my setup is using for some audit purposes and those versions are very well defined as I thought, especially in stand-alone applications using Core java not J2EE. My assumption of somehow jms 1.2 is linked to it could be wrong.

Comment: Well as I said the version of JNDI is the same as the version of the JDK/JRE since 2007. I don't see what JMS has to do with it.

Comment: The bigger question is where this non-existent JMS 1.2 specification version comes from. Probably a typo and its built against the JMS 1.1 spec.